# How to search in cassandra for map data type column?

Tags: php, cassandra

I am using map datatype for one column in `cassandra` which is storing values like

```
{
    'email':'example@example.com',
    'Id':2
}
```

How can I search for `email='example@example.com' OR Id = 2`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible in a straight forward way. For starters there is no `OR` operator in CQL. You would have to do the OR client side by merging the results of two queries.

Second, to do such a query you need a secondary index. But secondary indexes do not allow you (yet) to index both the key and the value of a map. From the [CQL 3.1](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddlIndexColl.html?scroll=ddlIndexColl__idxMap) documentation:

> Indexes on the keys and values of a map cannot co-exist.

So the closest you can get, as far as I can see, is one query with

```
the_map CONTAINS ('example@example.com')
```

and another one with

```
the_map CONTAINS ('2')
```

As long as it is guaranteed that the values of `email` and `ID` cannot overlap, the merged result of the two queries should give you the desired result. But there is no way to ensure that '2' actually was the value for the key `ID` or 'example@example.com' a value for the key `email`.